# Eclipselink with eclipselink tries insert in the parent table,

Tags: java, spring-mvc, eclipselink

I am stuck with the following problem:

everytime i try to create a bloco, eclipselink tries to insert a condominio record (which should be null ) , when i run the same code in a simple java project (without spring) it works fine, but in the web project it keeps trying to insert in the "parent" table.

any reason why eclipselink is trying to force a bidirectional relationship?

Entities

Condominio

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idcondominio")
private Integer idcondominio;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nomecond")
private String nomecond;
@Column(name = "cnpjcond")
private Integer cnpjcond;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "condominio")
private Collection<Bloco> blocoCollection;
```

Bloco

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected BlocoPK blocoPK;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nomebloco")
private String nomebloco;
@Column(name = "numero")
private String numero;
@JoinColumn(name = "condominio_idcondominio", referencedColumnName = "idcondominio", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Condominio condominio;
```

==============================
Create method

```
public void create(Bloco bloco) throws PreexistingEntityException, Exception {
    if (bloco.getBlocoPK() == null) {
        bloco.setBlocoPK(new BlocoPK());
    }
    bloco.getBlocoPK().setCondominioIdcondominio(bloco.getCondominio().getIdcondominio());
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Condominio condominio = bloco.getCondominio();
        if (condominio != null) {
            condominio = em.getReference(condominio.getClass(), condominio.getIdcondominio());
            bloco.setCondominio(condominio);
        }
        em.persist(bloco);
        if (condominio != null) {
            condominio.getBlocoCollection().add(bloco);
            condominio = em.merge(condominio);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (findBloco(bloco.getBlocoPK()) != null) {
            throw new PreexistingEntityException("Bloco " + bloco + " already exists.", ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

=========================
Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cadbloco", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String cadbloco(@ModelAttribute(value = "Bloco") Bloco bloco, @RequestParam("condid") int idcond ) throws Exception {

    BlocoJpaController jpa = new BlocoJpaController();
    Condominio c = new Condominio();
    c.setIdcondominio(idcond);
    jpa.create(bloco);

    return ("redirect:bloco.htm");

}
```

=====================

## ype Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nomecond' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO condominio (cnpjcond, nomecond) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Entity.Condominio[ idcondominio=null ])
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Comment: Show more information; Turn on EclipseLink logging to see SQL that is generated, and try calling em.flush after your persist call. Why are you using getReference instead of find? Presumably if the condominio is a part of the Bloco's PK, it really must exist before you can create the Condominio with this code. The only reason EclipseLink would try to insert a condominio instance is if it finds one that isn't managed by the EntityManager referenced by something that is. Check that this EM doesn't contain something else from earlier that it shouldn't.

Comment: It might help if you can disable constraint checking until the end of the transaction, as this would allow you to see all statements being issued. This might make it more obvious why this insert is happening, but you'll have to track down your model to see where there is an instance of Condominio with a null nomecond value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is que right method, i didnt set the condominio in bloco, so when i tried to create a new bloco it didnt have a condominio.

I new to this kind of stuff i make those kind of mistakes sometimes, but thanks for the help.

==================================================================

@RequestMapping(value = "cadbloco", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String cadbloco(@ModelAttribute(value = "Bloco") Bloco bloco, @RequestParam("condid") int idcond ) throws Exception {

```
    BlocoJpaController jpa = new BlocoJpaController();
    Condominio c = new Condominio();
    c.setIdcondominio(idcond);
    bloco.setCondominio(c);
    jpa.create(bloco);

    return ("redirect:bloco.htm");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception says "nomecond" value is null. So in your controller if you add the code that says

> c.setNomeCond("Some value");

That should fix the issue.,

Comment: I am trying to insert in "bloco" with a already created "condominio", and not creating a knew condominio, it is a one to many relationship,

Comment: then u will have to set the Condominio object to Bloco., bloco.setCondominio(c);

Comment: that was missing , but it is still trying to insert in the condominio table, i think it is some how forcing a bidirectonal relationship....